# How does soundcloud play music on multiple players?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, soundcloud, jplayer, soundmanager2

If you look in soundcloud you'll notice that when you play a song it plays in the main content of the page as well as a 'footer' player. I'm trying to achieve something similar, with jplayer or soundmanager. My main content of my pages are ajaxed while the footer stays consistent to support the continious player of the website.

But my question is, how do you play music from the ajaxed footer player while animating the main content player and having seek functions on both?

Answer (score 0):

With jPlayer I assume you would need to listen for `$.jPlayer.event.play`, `$.jPlayer.event.pause`, `$.jPlayer.event.ended`, `$.jPlayer.event.seeked` in your main player and update secondary interface.

You may need to create secondary interface yourself (play/pause buttons, seek bar, etc) and add event handlers for them passing corresponding parameters to the main player.